# RStudio Cloud: R 4.0.0 Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, updates, reinstall

I recently logged back on to my RStudio Cloud and wanted to keep working on my project. Upon trying to continue, the following error message occurred:

**Error: package ‘rmarkdown’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it**

I removed markdown from my packages and reinstalled it. This did not solve the problem. I do not remember updating my RStudio. How do I fix this? I really need to continue working on this project.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `install.packages('rmarkdown', dep = TRUE)` maybe

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I ended up leaving it be for a few days and it updated itself.